# Why does iterating over a HashMap<&str,&str> yield a &&str?

Tags: string, hashmap, pattern-matching, rust

I'm iterating over a `HashMap` and putting the values in it via pattern matching in some local vars.

**Delegater**

```
fn lyrics_no_bottles(song_template:&mut String){
    let mut template_partials = HashMap::new();

    template_partials.insert("start", "No more bottles");
    template_partials.insert("repeat", "no more bottles");
    template_partials.insert("remaining", "99 bottles");
    template_partials.insert("message", "Go to the store and buy some more");

    resolve_template(song_template, template_partials);
}
```

**Called**

```
fn resolve_template(song_template:&mut String, partials: HashMap<&str, &str>){
    let start:&str;
    let repeat:&str;
    let remaining:&str;
    let message:&str;

    for key in partials.keys(){
        match key {
            "start" => start = partials.get(key),
            "repeat" => repeat = partials.get(key),
            "remaining" => remaining = partials.get(key),
            "message" => message = partials.get(key)
        }
    }

    *song_template = song_template.replace("%1", start);
    *song_template = song_template.replace("%2", repeat);
    *song_template = song_template.replace("%3", message);
    *song_template = song_template.replace("%4", remaining);
}
```

**Error Output**

```
lib.rs:51:5: 58:6 error: type mismatch resolving `<std::collections::hash::map::Keys<'_, &str, &str> as core::iter::Iterator>::Item == &str`:
 expected &-ptr,
    found str [E0271]
lib.rs:51     for key in partials.keys(){
lib.rs:52         match key {
lib.rs:53             "start" => start = partials.get(key),
lib.rs:54             "repeat" => repeat = partials.get(key),
lib.rs:55             "remaining" => remaining = partials.get(key),
lib.rs:56             "message" => message = partials.get(key)
          ...
lib.rs:51:5: 58:6 help: run `rustc --explain E0271` to see a detailed explanation
lib.rs:53:32: 53:49 error: mismatched types:
 expected `&str`,
    found `core::option::Option<&&str>`
(expected &-ptr,
    found enum `core::option::Option`) [E0308]
lib.rs:53             "start" => start = partials.get(key),
```

I don't understand why the compiler thinks there is a `&&str` when I declared the parameter as `HashMap<&str,&str>`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because [that particular method returns a reference wrapped by an Option](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get).

Basically, if you store a `String` there and use `get` .. you'll get an `Option<&String>` as the result of a call to `get`. Storing `&str` will return you an `Option<&&str>` as the result of a call to `get`.

Examples of values and how they'll appear when you call `get`:

```
String -> Option<&String>
&str -> Option<&&str>
u32 -> Option<&u32>
```

Ownership of the `&str` is being transferred to the hashmap when you insert it in as a value. The hashmap therefore returns references to them for you using `get` ... or [mutable references using get_mut](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get_mut).

The playground is currently broken (can't share anything from it) ... so here is a working .. broken down sample of your code:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut map: HashMap<&str, &str> = HashMap::new();
    map.insert("start", "value");

    let mut start: &str = "Unknown";
    let mut repeat: &str;
    let mut remaining: &str;
    let mut message: &str;

    for key in map.keys() {
        match &key[..] {
            "start" => start = map.get(key).unwrap(),
            "repeat" => repeat = map.get(key).unwrap(),
            "remaining" => remaining = map.get(key).unwrap(),
            "message" => message = map.get(key).unwrap(),
            _ => unreachable!()
        }
    }

    println!("Result: {}", start);
}
```

Comment: So I also have to destruct the `Option<&&str>` before I even can deref the `&&str` ...I'll try a `if let Some(x)`

Comment: Correct. Perhaps I should give you a fix for your actual issue in my answer as well. I'll add that now.

Comment: thank you...am not getting it to work with if let anyway

Comment: can you explain `&key[..]` further?

Comment: Oh sure - sorry, its just baked in my brain (and I wrote this on the train on my tablet). Basically you only want a way to allow your match arms to match identical types. Your `key` is `&&str`.. and the match arms are `&'static str`. They aren't comparable. You can use any method you want to dereference the `key` variable. So these will all work: `*key`, `&key[..]`, `key.as_ref()`, etc.